# What are vornoi diagrams used for in game development

Tags: algorithm

I see vornoi diagrams talked about from time to time in the context of game development and graphics, and have seen them used a bit in procedural textures as well as talked about in relation to path finding (I think...).  I kmow vornoi regions are also sometimes used in collision tests, but that isn't quite the same as a vornoi diagrams.

Are vornoi actually used in any actual path finding implementations (I know about A* and variants, navmeshes)?

What else are vornoi diagrams used for in game dev or graphics?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems like it could only be answered with an exhaustive list. [Just searching for other questions & answers that include the term "voronoi"](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=voronoi) would probably be equally informative.

Comment: Interesting question, I always thought they were good just for theory (and "nice" shapes). They are dual to delaunay triangulation though, which is used extensively.

Comment: Also see http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-voronoi-diagrams-to-control-ai--gamedev-11778